# Ceiling fan with light, 3 way wall switch and remote

Tags: ceiling-fan

I am installing a new fan in my bedroom.  I would like to control the light on the fan with a wall switch.  I would also like to control the fan by using the included remote.  My fan comes with just a remote.

I was following this thread: [How do I wire a hard-wired wall switch and a remote for my ceiling fan/light?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/58797/how-do-i-wire-a-hard-wired-wall-switch-and-a-remote-for-my-ceiling-fan-light)

And I was reading the response from ThreePhasEel.  His option three is exactly what I am trying to accomplish.  The only difference is my power is coming from the swich.

I have Black, White, Ground coming into the box.  I then plan on running 12/4 romex up to the fan box.  This is where I am hoping to hook up the fan and the relay mentioned in the above referenced post.

I was hoping someone could help tell me how to wire it properly with the power being in the wall switch versus the fan itself.

I am pasting from the other thread here for reference.

> Blockquote
>   [image: Image I am trying to duplicate but with power from switch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... and here's how you do that thing.

[image]

*Travelers marked with purple tape, since every other color seems to be used :)*

- Note the power entering at the switch means the 3-way complex (3-way+relay) is reversed: Power comes from the 3-way, via one of the 2 travelers, to the relay then onward to the fan/light.
- The /4 is used to carry 2 travelers, always-hot (black) and neutral (white) onward to the rest of the circuit, including to the receiver.
- Since we have 2 groups of neutrals in close proximity, neutrals on the receiver side are now marked with gray tape
- Dimmer 3-way changed out to plain 3-way.  It doesn't really matter though; it could be left a dimmer 3-way.

Comment: I was looking at wiring this last night and had one additional question.  Based on how the fan is wired from the factory it would be easier for me to tie the "Coil Neutral" to the "in neutral."  This would prevent having to run an additional wire down into the fan.  From what I can tell (and like you mentioned) we are passing the hot along the travelers.  Can you confirm I am interpreting this correctly?  Thanks in advance.  I really do appreciate your help!

Comment: Generally you should use the neutral that's partnered to the hot you are using.  It's possible the neutral simply is a passthru, but only the device's documentation will tell.  Anyway due to the many interconnects, I would except the module and relay to both live right up in the top of the fan, where (actual) wire runs should be very short.   From the 3-way, always-hot+neutral are delivered on black+white, and power is also delivered via one of the two travelers (swapping when you throw the switch). If you need always-hot, tap black. You must use /4 cable here; *it can't be done in /3*.

Comment: I wanted to say thank you again. If I could give more votes I would. This solved my problem! I had spent hours searching for a solution. It works perfectly. I can turn my light on from the wall and off with the remote. And the fan is controlled from the remote. Switch on wall set to off and fan still works. Thank you!